# Minimum sample size for cross-sectional RDD

Tags: applied-econometrics, empirical-methods, identification

I haven't done a regression discontinuity design (RDD) before. I know it requires a large sample size for identification, thus I fear that my sample size is not large enough.

The study is cross-sectional, not longitudinal.
Entire sample size is around 1000, and the sample size around the cutoff point is around 100.

Is it enough for a cross-sectional fuzzy RDD?

What is the "minimum" sample size and "good-enough" sample size for cross-sectional fuzzy (sharp) RDD?

Answer (score 1):

I've run RDDs on similar sample sizes and got the paper accepted at a respectable conference. It's important to run McCrary Density Tests on your sample to look for people using knowledge on the treatment assignment rule to manipulate results and - even more important - to have a clear identification strategy, a qualitative justification for what you're doing.